# Issue regarding variables conflict on client machines after publishing application

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, session, iis

I am new to deploying asp.net web application in server where multiple users can login the application and use system at same time. I have completed development of system and now is ready to be deployed. My doubt is regarding the conflict due to muli-users access at same time. As multiple users will be accessing the system from different client computer, will the values stored in class file or session variable i have created in my application conflict on multiple access? How can I prevent if this happens? What is the best practise for resolving these issues?
Any help?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which issue ? each request and session is technically separate from every other.

Comment: thanks for your reply aria.. this means there is no conflict on varaibles on accessing application from different sites?? is this separation done by IIS?

Comment: Also, a variable in a page such as int m_Int = 0;, lives only as long as the page does. Pages cease to exist as soon as they are served to the browser and thus all the objects in them are destroyed (http is stateless after all). Keeping them alive in session does limit them to that session state, which should be limited to that user. Application level variables, and objects declared as static, exist for all users though so be careful in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net will manage session and variables itself,
you don't worry about session conflict because each request and session is technically separate from every other, 
ASP.NET uses highly random 120-bit numbers for its session IDs so it's almost impossible to get duplicate ID,

If you want to keep you session unique and alive in every condition  the use SessionStateMode as StateServer which provides the required functionality.

for more information [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) and [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683(VS.71).aspx) can be useful for you, but about static global variable it's preferred to avoid them and you should take a little care see [Here](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/avoid-static-variables-in-asp-net/)